# Same literate defination causes different behaviour

Tags: listings

The code of following two examples has the same `literate` defination. The literate `A!` is used to emphasize some code by color and size. The literate `!A` is used to restore the color.

In the first example, I want the code `pt` to be emphasized and it does work all right.

In the second example, I want the code `\expandafter\@firstoftwo` to be emphasized, but the red color extends to end, and `\huge` behaves oddly.

Why? And what's wrong with my codes?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\begin{document}
Exp 1:
\begin{lstlisting}[literate={A!}{{\huge\color{red}\bfseries}}0{!A}{{\normalcolor}}0]
\ifdim \stwo A!pt!A >\sone pt $<$\else $\geq$\fi
\end{lstlisting}

Exp 2:
\begin{lstlisting}[literate={A!}{{\huge\color{red}\bfseries}}0{!A}{{\normalcolor}}0]
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myConditionTF[1]{%
  #1% or something like \ifx..., \if\empty..., and so on.
  A!\expandafter\@firstoftwo!A
  \else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All right. I'll delete all my comments

Comment: I wouldn't use literate for this, but moredelim, e.g. `\begin{lstlisting}[moredelim={[is][\huge\bfseries\color{red}]{A!}{!A}}]`

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer 
Many thanks! The typeset of literate`\expandafter\@firstoftwo` by `moredelim` seems like a bit ugly(charactors overlapped). I think it may be caused by `\huge`. If `\huge`  is mandatory how can I improve it?